# PathParam how to set Regex to allow URL?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am using @PathParam and the request format is like this:

```
@Path("/XXX/XXX/{testvariable:[\\\\s\\\\S]+}")
```

Here, testvariable can take values like http://google.com/myname.txt, 191.123.122.333 or in short a String with any special characters. The regex that I used doesn't seem to allow the value "http://google.com/myname.txt" for this.

I get response saying, `.No operation matching request path`.

Comment: Could you post your request URI along with the code for your method? I couldn't reproduce the problem

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
I am afraid I cannot give the exact code, here is the method

@Path("/Data/{SomeID:[\\s\\S]+}")
  @Produces( { "application/xml", "application/json" })
  public Response getData( @PathParam("SomeID") String SomeID) 
  {
//
}

and here is how i access the method :

http://localhost:8080/Data/http://google.com/myname.txt

I expect to get this http://google.com/myname.txt as SomeID in this method. 

NB: I use Rest Client to test this.

Comment: Does the URL work at all?  (i.e. can you match other values like "/Data/abcd?)

You may also want to try using "/XXX/XXX/{testvariable:.+}"

I couldn't reproduce the problem with Apache Wink but you may also want to try using the URL encoded version: http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fmyname.txt so: localhost:8080/Data//http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fmyname.txt .  Depending on your servlet container, the two slashes // may get truncated since it's an "empty" path.